# How to iterate a list or vector of numbers containing decimals in Julia?

Tags: loops, julia

```
function distribucion(x::Vector)
    for i in x
        if x[i] > 1
            return error("The values have to be between 0 and 1")
        elseif x[i] < 0
            return error("The values have to be between 0 and 1")
        end
    end 
end

x = collect(0:0.01:1) 
distribucion(x) Error:ArgumentError:invalid index:0.0 type Float64
```

How can I iterate a vector that contains decimals between 0 and 1? What happens is that I declared a function that receives a vector but when iterating and putting conditionals it shows me an error:

```
Error:ArgumentError:invalid index:0.0 type Float64
```

Comment: `for i in x` already iterates the values. Using `x[i[` isn't valid. Just test `i`. NB You can combine those two tests.

Comment: If you want the indices, you must ask for them by writing `for i in eachindex(x)`.

Comment: Err, using `x[i]` isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

It will be much faster if you provide a predicate to `any` or `all` functions in Julia because it avoids allocating a new array. The easiest in your case might be `@assert all(i->0<=i<=1, x)`, but if you want a specific error message, you can use the following:

```
@assert all(i->0<=i<=1, x) "All values have to be between 0 and 1"
```

This has zero allocations and is about 4X faster than `0 .<= x .<= 1`. It also works for scalars, vectors, or matrices.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comment above:

```
function distribucion(x::Vector)
    for elem in x # iterate elements of vector
        if elem > 1 || elem < 0
            return error("The values have to be between 0 and 1, the value received was ", elem)
        end
    end
end

x =collect(0:0.01:1)
append!(x, 2.1) # test
distribucion(x)
```

Comment: You can chain comparisons like this: `!(0 < elem < 1)`. Also, the `error` function _throws_ an error, so no point in putting `return` in front of it, since the function doesn't actually return.

Answer (score 0):

This code could be also written as:

```
function distribution(x)
    @assert all(0 .<= x .<= 1) "The values have to be between 0 and 1"
end
```

This works with any x (scalar, `Vector`, `Matrix`) - in Julia there is usually no need to limit the argument type.
Note the dot operator (`.`) that vectorizes the comparison operation.